# MongoDB enable oplog windows

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-oplog

Try to enable oplog locally

Add to `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.cfg`

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
  oplogSizeMB: 100
```

Restart mongod, but local.oplog does not exist

How correctly enable oplog?

UPD: Use MongoDB 4.2, Windows 10

Comment: please also mention MongoDB version, Operating system as well

Comment: @ManjeetThakur added to the question

Comment: If you are trying to [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) you need to run [`rs.initiate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/) to create a replica set configuration and initial oplog. If you've already done this, please edit your question to confirm how you are checking for the existence of the oplog. You can use `rs.printReplicationInfo()` in the `mongo` shell to confirm the configured oplog size as well as first and last events.

Comment: @Stennie , run mongod with `--replSet rs0` then run `rs.initiate()`, oplog start work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the replication configs in the `mongod.cfg` file.
2. Restart MongoDB from services.
3. Open MongoDB from a command prompt.
4. Execute the following command in the mongo terminal:

   ```
   rs.initiate({_id:"rs0", members: [{"_id":1, "host":"127.0.0.1:27017"}]})
   ```

   After that you'll see something like this:

   ```
   {
       "info" : "Config now saved locally.  Should come online in about a minute.",
       "ok" : 1
   }
   ```
5. Switch to the local database using `use local`.
6. You can verify `oplog.rs` by viewing the collections using: `show collections`

You'll see that `oplog.rs` will be listed along with other collections.

```
oplog.rs
replset.election
replset.minvalid
replset.oplogTruncateAfterPoint
startup_log
system.replset
system.rollback.id
```